# Stale Data Count

Tags: sql

So I have a table called: EQ

My current data is as follows. Date range is between 11/01/2018 to 11/30/2018

My end result is to be able to know how many days of stale price are there for each of the Item in that period? and also if possible the date a new price has been added? Otherwise the former will suffice.

[Current Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMOfP.jpg)

```
  Date  Product Item    Price
11/1/2018   Item A          101
            Item B          101
11/2/2018   Item A          101
            Item B          101
11/3/2018   Item A          101
            Item B          101
11/4/2018   Item A          101
            Item B          101
11/5/2018   Item A          101
            Item B          101
11/6/2018   Item A          101
            Item B          101
11/7/2018   Item A          101
            Item B          101
11/8/2018   Item A          101
        Item B              101
11/9/2018   Item A          101
        Item B              101
11/10/2018  Item A          101
        Item B              101
11/11/2018  Item A          101
        Item B              101
11/12/2018  Item A          100
        Item B              101
11/13/2018  Item A          100
           Item B           102
```

Comment: What database are you using?  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.  Some examples of database vendors include MySQL, SQL Server, and Oracle.

Comment: Add your sample data in text format rather than link to an image.

Comment: This is the kind of query I will run:  go
select *
from eq.db
where date is between '2018/11/01' and '2018/11/30'
and product item in ('Item A', 'Item B')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An inner query to count number of prices per product and price that exists more than once and then the outer query to sum on product

```
SELECT product_item, SUM(item_count) 
FROM 
 (SELECT product_item, price, count(*) as item_count
  FROM EQ
  WHERE date >= '2018/11/01'
    AND date <= '2018/11/30'
  GROUP BY product_item, price
  HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)) AS a
GROUP BY product_item
```

I am not sure what date format to use so you need to adjust that

Comment: because my table is EQ and I need a date range, does this work?     SELECT product_item, SUM(count) 
FROM EQ
where date between '2018/11/01' and '2018/11/30'
 (SELECT product_item, price, count(*) as count
  FROM prices 
  GROUP BY product_item, price
  HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)) AS a
GROUP BY product_item

Comment: @newnew Sorry I didn't see the name of your table and I missed the date range but it should work. I update my answer

Comment: I got this error:   Incorrect syntax near ')'.
 Msg: 102, Level: 15, State: 181
 Server: XXX1, Line: 1 

>[Error] Script lines: 603-612 ----------------------
 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'count'.
 Msg: 156, Level: 15, State: 2
 Server: XXX1, Line: 3

Comment: maybe the issue is that count is considered as a reserved word and it can't be used. rename it to something else. You still haven't saidwhat database you are using, please tag your question with it. Also you could execute the inner query separately to make sure it works

Comment: Sorry the database is Sybase